# SQL Server insert em um campo money

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como fazer insert em um campo do tipo money?

Preciso inserir um campo do tipo money no SQL server e dá erro. Devo declarar como uma string?

Comment: Você esta tentando fazer o insert de uma string formatada/mascarada, algo como `R$ 100,00` ([apesar da sintaxe suportar alguns símbolos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5j8p.png)), isso não é um numero, você tem que ajustar o seu código para trabalhar como numero, é só aplicar a mascara/formatação na exibição final para o usuário.

Answer (score 2):

O tipo money deve ser inserido igual a um tipo float ou double.

Segundo a documentação:

> Os tipos de dados money e smallmoney têm a precisão de dez milésimos das unidades monetárias que eles representam.
>
> Use um ponto para separar unidades monetárias parciais, como centavos, de unidades monetárias inteiras. Por exemplo, 2.15 especifica 2 reais e 15 centavos.

[fonte](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Desta forma, se deseja inserir um valor do tipo money seguindo este modelo relacional (DDL):

```
CREATE TABLE conta (
    id int primary key,
    grana MONEY
);
```

temos a seguinte sintaxe para inserção (DML):

```
INSERT INTO conta ([id], [grana]) VALUES (1, 50);
INSERT INTO conta ([id], [grana]) VALUES (2, 0.5);
INSERT INTO conta ([id], [grana]) VALUES (3, 1);
```

Note que

> Dados de moeda ou monetários não precisam ser incluídos entre
> aspas simples ( ' ). É importante lembrar que apesar de você poder
> especificar valores monetários precedidos por um símbolo de moeda, o
> SQL Server não armazena quaisquer informações de moeda associada com o
> símbolo, só armazena o valor numérico.